# Nodemcu + GSM IOT-GA6

Tags: serial, gsm, nodemcu

I've connected my NodeMCU to GSM module using GND, RX and TX.

I use At Comand Tester. When I try to get sim status or something I get error for example:

> Unable to get Sim status.

Only AT comand returns

> AT
>
> OK

When I send any AT comand to GSM module I can see that the diode on the module blink.

How can I solve this problem?

Let me know if you need more informations to help me.

Comment: Please, post your full code, schematic circuit (also a picture if you want) and GSM module model.

Comment: Gsm module is in the post's title. If I test with at comands it means that I don't have any code. Pictures I will add as soon as it is possible

Comment: [link](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=579036.0) I'm trying to use this module

Comment: I mean, what sketch are you upload on NodeMCU board?

Comment: I have't uploaded anything